# Facebook´s Conversion API Custom Audience

Tags: javascript, api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I´m trying to create a Custom Audience on Facebook´s Conversion API following this guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/audience-rules

Ive got my data on a JSON:

```
       const rule = {
"inclusions": {
    "operator": "or",   // Required. and or or.
    "rules": [{
        "retention_seconds": 3500, //Required.  Integer (in seconds) for the retention window of the audience. Min=1; Max=365 days
        "event_sources": [{
            "id": "<OFFLINE_EVENT_SET_ID>",
            "type": "offline_events"
        }],
    "filter": {
            "operator": "and", // Required. and or or.
            "filters": [{
                    "operator": "=", //If field set to event, must use =.
                    "field": "event", //event
                    "value": "purchase"
                },
                {
                    "operator": ">",
                    "field": "value",
                    "value": "50"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}
}

const audienceData = {
      "name": "Customs",
      "rule": rule,
      "access_token": access_token
  }
```

Pushing it with axios:

```
 async function CustomAudience(audience) {
    try {
        return await axios.post(`https://graph.facebook.com/${api_version}/${audienceID}/users`, audience);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

customAudience(audienceData);
```

I know i can do it with offline conversions, (among other things, because it gives me the option on field)

```
For Store Visits Custom Audiences, use 'event' or store_visit_country.
```

**My question is regarding "retention seconds"**

as they are offline conversions, I do not have retention_seconds, and according to the documentation, they are **required**, and I can not modify my JSON data, as it comes from a CRM.

And when you do a Custom Audience manually, you do not have to specify retention_seconds...

What is the best practice here? Re build a JSON and add a fake retention_seconds seems dirty, but its a required field...

Comment: _“and I can not modify my JSON data, as it comes from a CRM.”_ - but the Axios code you have shown is “yours”, is it not? Then I don’t see any reason why you should not be able to make changes to what that `audienceData` variable contains at that point?

Comment: Yes I can make any change at that level, but the question is what should I add? I dont want to add any made up retention_seconds value, I cant find any default value, and as its required, its got to be in. So its a question of "what" more than "how".

Comment: _“as they are offline conversions, I do not have retention_seconds”_ - but even Facebook’s own examples under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/offline-custom-audiences use them. _“For example, to target people who spent more than USD1000 in the past 90 days”_ – and then they use `"retention_seconds":7776000` accordingly. Who do you want to target with your custom audience here, if you say you don’t have any retention_seconds? People who did something in the last _zero_ seconds? I can’t see your scenario making much sense yet, tbh.